# how to get direction in iphone?

Tags: iphone

i am implementing application same as wickitude application apple store.I want to use wickitude api in my application.but i dont know how to use it.plese help me for this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean "Wikitude", start [here](http://www.wikitude.org/developers).

> The WIKITUDE API package includes the
>   following:The Wikitude Java API;
>   javadocs; documentation and a sample
>   application.